# Excel formula in counting distance between a specific value in rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am dealing with unlimited data that keeps adding a combination of rows every-time. I wanted a formula that would count the row distance between the First Lower limit to the Second Lower Limit. Please no VBA i want a formula only or array formula perhaps. I would truly appreciate it if someone could help. I have been trying to figure this out for months now.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Could you please leave a comment at my answer, why it didn't work for you? The results are exactly what you ask for in your screen Example. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Paste in cell I2 and commit as an array-formula [control-shift-enter]. Then pull down.

```
=IF(LARGE(IF((A$1:F$1000=H2),ROW(A$1:A$1000),0),2)=0,0,LARGE(IF((A$1:F$1000=H2),ROW(A$1:A$1000),0),1)-LARGE(IF((A$1:F$1000=H2),ROW(A$1:A$1000),0),2))+1
```

Answer (score 0):

array formula:

```
{=SMALL(IF((C:C=E7),ROW(A:A),2^20),1)-SMALL(IF((B:B=E7),ROW(A:A),2^20),1)+1}
```

fill up and down.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work with the other values sir try putting 111 to cell "A5"

Comment: u must define the distance of which column to which column. my formula is for column B and C. you can adjust the formula to find for the distance between other two columns.

Comment: you are showing 6 columns of data, i'm not sure how the data is defined or if it is just a sample. But with 6 columns of data, there would be 15 combination of distances